# How do I add custom headers to SignalR's Typescript client?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, signalr

I am trying to pass a bearer token in the header to authorize client connections. The SignalR hub authorizes client by grabbing the bearer token from the header. I cannot modify the SingalR hub code to use a query string to get the token, nor can I use the built-in JWT token functionality.

How do I add a custom header to the SignalR typescript client?

The only thing I can think to do is override the HttpClient in to add the header however I am not sure if this is possible or how to do this.

I am using @microsoft/signalr in Angular 8 and the latest @microsoft/signalr package.

Comment: Show me the code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add a custom HttpClient in the options when building the connection.

It would look something like this:

```
class CustomHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {
  public send(request: HttpRequest): Promise<HttpResponse> {
    request.headers = { ...request.headers, "customHeader": "value" };
    return super.send(request);
  }
}

let hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(url, { httpClient: new CustomHttpClient() })
    .build();
```

It is possible to inherit from the `DefaultHttpClient` and in your send you call the DefaultHttpClient's send so you don't need to implement the Http calls yourself.

First class support has been implemented in 5.0 or higher of the @microsoft/signalr package via the `headers` property on `IHttpConnectionOptions`, see https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14588 for the resolved GitHub issue.

Comment: It should be noted that setting headers when using the WebSockets transport will not work. I am only sure of this for the JavaScript client, but I believe it will apply to all of the SignalR clients.

Comment: @Hedgybeats Yes, that's true. To set headers on the Javascript client, transport type needs to be explicitly provided as `LongPolling`. It won't work for either `WebSockets` or `ServerSentEvents`.

Answer (score 8):

If this is just to pass a bearer token then no need to do custom headers, to pass an access token you can use withUrl overload that takes IHttpConnectionOptions, this interface has accessTokenFactory that can be used like this:

```
yourAuthServicePromise.then(
  (data) => {
    if (data.['result']['accessToken']) {
      this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('https://SIGNALR_SERVER_HUB_URL', {
          accessTokenFactory: () => {
            return data.['result']['accessToken'];
          }
        } as signalR.IHttpConnectionOptions)
        .build();
      this.hubConnection.start()
    }
  }
);
```

Don't forget to enable cors policy in the hub Server in order to allow the JS client origin

Answer (score 6):

I needed something exactly like @Brennan's answer.

I have just filled in some of the gaps which were missing for a more copy and pastable answer. I am using this and it works, thanks @Brennan

```
import * as signalR from "@aspnet/signalr";

// You can create a factory which signalR will used to generate an access token on each request
const getBearerToken = () => "MY TOKEN GETTING FUNCTION"

// This is a custom method which creates all the headers I need for my authentication
const getAuthHeaders = () => ({ collection: "", of: "", headers:""})

// As per @Brennan's answer I used his advice and extened the default one
class CustomHttpClient extends signalR.DefaultHttpClient {
  constructor() {
    super(console); // the base class wants an signalR.ILogger, I'm not sure if you're supposed to put *the console* into it, but I did and it seemed to work
  }

  // So far I have only overriden this method, and all seems to work well
  public async send(request: signalR.HttpRequest): Promise<signalR.HttpResponse> {
    var authHeaders = getAuthHeaders(); // These are the extra headers I needed to put in
    request.headers = { ...request.headers, ...authHeaders };
    // Now we have manipulated the request how we want we can just call the base class method
    return super.send(request);
  }
}

 let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(`${apiUrl}/web-sockets/stripeHub`, {
        accessTokenFactory: getBearerToken, // I also needed this, but you may not need it
        httpClient: new CustomHttpClient(), // This is the CustomClient we defined above which adds the headers to each request going out
     }) 
    .build();
```

Answer (score 5):

There is an option called `headers` while creating hub connection builder. and this option is available only when you use `@microsoft/signalr` npm package. this is the active repo for signalr and the older one [(@aspnet/signalr)](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR) has been archived.

So with new npm package, you can do like below

```
let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
.withUrl("/chat", { 
 headers: { 
   "custom-header-name": "value" 
 },
 withCredentials: (true/false) // if you dont mention this value (if undefined by default it will set to true (which i didnt wanted in my case)
})
.build();
```

**Note:** keep in mind that, by default automatic reconnect is false, so add `withUrl().withAutomaticReconnect()`
if you want.

More about the [options interface](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/61cdc605a8a5ad8af7189ebb21b4a996bc77833d/src/SignalR/clients/ts/signalr/src/IHttpConnectionOptions.ts#L11)

Comment: I tried to pass the custum-header-name  this is not working