# How to pass headers to signalr hub using typescript client (Signalr Core)

Tags: angular, typescript, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr, signalr-client

I want to pass a header through my Hubconnection builder to my signalrHub.
In other words, how do I accomplish this Using typescript.

Here is the C# implementation I have:

```
connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                    .WithUrl("https://localhost:53251" + "/simpleHub", options =>
                    {
                        //set the header
                        options.Headers.Add("Device-ID", deviceID);
                    })
                    .Build();
```

How can I do the same with typescript client ?
I tried several things I found online, the latest was :

```
 this._hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("https://localhost:53251" + "/simpleHub?Device-ID=fc8dsc72f-1456-4bc2-b1ea-ac34b9c3559e", {
        })
        .configureLogging(LogLevel.Debug)
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .build();
```

But Passing the header this way, causes the server not to receive the header. Please does anyone have a solution ? please.

Comment: Have you installed the `@aspnet/signalr` npm package? There is a good walkthrough of how to hook things up here: https://code-maze.com/netcore-signalr-angular/

Comment: thanks @paul but my question is about passing headers, not about installing signalr

Comment: it was a guess. Your description of the problem, "it does not work", didn't leave me much to go on.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59652214/how-do-i-add-custom-headers-to-signalrs-typescript-client

Comment: @Brennan thanks, but that solution didn't work for me... I think I'll update this question for it to be clear

Comment: @paul that package is obsolete and is not supported by Microsoft, they migrated to ```@microsoft/signalr```.

Comment: At least in version 5.0.5 of @microsoft/signalr there is a way to specify custom headers: `.withUrl('/chat', { headers: { ... })`