# How to pass request headers set using headers option for ServerSideEvent (If Platform is browser) in React js

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I have got to know that, the new npm package `@microsoft/signalR` provided options to pass custom header to httpClient used to make SSE calls in javascript (using `headers` option in `withUrl`).

But found a difference in the code ([git code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/SignalR/clients/ts/signalr/src/ServerSentEventsTransport.ts#L66)) where I see, the same custom header isn't forwarded if the request is from Browser or WebWorker. If otherwise, it is forwareded ([git code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/SignalR/clients/ts/signalr/src/ServerSentEventsTransport.ts#L75))

I would like to understand, is there a security reason for not forwarding the header? If yes, is there a way to get it working? i.e, set custom header when making HTTP requests if the transport type is SSE (ServerSentEvent).

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because browsers do not support sending headers with EventSource
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource/EventSource

Comment: Thanks for the response. So there isn't a way to send headers while using SSE from the browser? In my case, I have an API gateway for each API request. so I need to add api-key in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question for future readers.

I have got it working for my requirement, Where I need to pass custom headers to all the signalR calls irrespective of transport type, starting from the negotiate call.

I could be able to send the custom header using the `headers` option while creating `hubConnectionBuilder.withUrl(url, options)` [(have given detailed answer here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59652214/how-do-i-add-custom-headers-to-signalrs-typescript-client/67148866#67148866)

**To the point:**

For SSE, as mentioned by Brennan, we cant set the custom header with the Native EventSource constructor. But I have achieved it using the EventSource polyfill using this package ([npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-source-polyfill))

Two points to note down, if you are using signalR and try to achieve the same as mine.

1. By default signalR uses native EventSource, but there is a property we can set in the same options parameter in `withUrl`.
2. Extend the polyfill constructor and add the custom headers.

```js
import { EventSourcePolyfill } from 'event-source-polyfill';

function EventSourceWithCustomHeader(url, options) {
  return new EventSourcePolyfill(url, { 
        ...options, 
        headers: { 
           ...options.headers, 
           "custom-header-name": "value" 
        } 
    });
}


const conn = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                   .withUrl("/chat", { 
                     headers: { 
                        "custom-header-name": "value" 
                    },
                    EventSource: EventSourceWithCustomHeader,
             })
             .build();
```

Comment: Oh interesting, wasn't aware that the polyfill used Xhr to implement SSE :)