# SignalR Custom Authorize Attribute

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, authorize-attribute, authorize

I am trying to implement custom Authorize attribute for .net 5 SignalR component. When I use the attribute, It is being ignored and doesn't get into the custom Authorize class.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
    public class IdentitySignalRAuthorizeAttribute : Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private Role[] _roles;
        public IdentitySignalRAuthorizeAttribute(params Role[] roles)
        {
            _roles = roles;
        }

        public override bool AuthorizeHubConnection(HubDescriptor hubDescriptor, IRequest request)
        {
            return base.AuthorizeHubConnection(hubDescriptor, request);
        }

        public override bool AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(IHubIncomingInvokerContext hubIncomingInvokerContext, bool appliesToMethod)
        {
            return base.AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(hubIncomingInvokerContext, appliesToMethod);
        }


    }

  public enum Role
    {
        Admin,
        User
    }
       Usage:
        [IdentitySignalRAuthorize(Role.User)]        
        public async Task InitConnectionAsync(...)
```

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm experiencing the same issue

Comment: No luck with this. Did you make any headway.

Comment: No.. I had to move secure endpoints off SignalR and use it without Auth. Terrible

Comment: FInally, I got it working. I tried to solve this problem via authorization attributes in .net Core, but that did not help. I ended up implementing my own HttpClient (in TypeScript) and adding it to the HubConnectionBuilder like so:

 this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('https://localhost/myapi/myhub', {
          accessTokenFactory: () => 'my whatever access_token',
          httpClient: new CustomHttpClient()
        })
        .build();

More info here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63157626/1485246